# Represent of a collection of binary data

Tags: performance, haskell, memory, optimization

I'm working with signals in which the samples consist of `Float`s. Some of the algorithms I've written only require to know when the signal crosses the x-axis (i.e. positive value to a negative value and vice versa). When I'm doing these kinds of operations, I realized that I don't need to know the actual `Float` value of each sample. I just need to know whether the sample's value is positive or not.

I originally represented the signal as a `Vector` of `Float`s. After my discovery, I started representing it as a `Vector` of `Boolean` values (i.e. `False` for a negative value and `True` for a positive value). This turned out to be a lot more efficient and I improved the program's performance both in terms of run-time and memory consumption.

I'm still wondering if there isn't a more efficient way of representing this "collection of binary data". Something like a `Bit Vector` or `Bit Array`. I've found a [BitArray](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bitarray-0.0.1.1/docs/Data-BitArray.html) on Hackage but it doesn't seem to support the same functionality that a `Vector` does.

Is there a more efficient way of representing the data of my use case or should I stick to a `Vector` of `Boolean` values?

Comment: What functionalities of a `Vector` do you need?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem The standard Haskell List primitives (i.e. map, fold, filter, etc.) I also use `V.generate` to read all the samples form a file.

Comment: The C++ standard library includes [a template specialisation for `bool`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) that uses the full content of the bytes for space efficiency... but this is [widely considered a bad idea now](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/on-vectorbool). Performance tends to be substantially _worse_ for such vectors, because element accesses can not be performed directly with pointer arithmetic anymore. — If you want to efficiently represent only the sign of a continuous signal, you should consider storing only the _spots where the sign changes_.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I already first read all samples from the file and convert them to `Bool` values. Then I convert this `Vector` to a `Vector` of the spots where the sign changes. But at that point, I've already stored the full `Vector` so I don't think it will give me an advantage. I don't know of a way to directly load the spots where the sign changes from a file. But I could think about that a little more carefully.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Also, for some applications I require to know where the sign changes from positive to negative, for other applications I require the opposite and for other applications I require to know both. That would mean that I have to save where the sign changes + the type of change. I curious as to how efficient that is.

Comment: Well, if you first need to read float values from a file there won't be much else you can usefully do to improve performance. To reduce _memory_, you can side-step the PCM vector entirely and deserialise the sign-changes information straight from a lazy bytestring ([`binary`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary) makes this easy); this will only require 1-2 _chunks_ in memory at a time.

Comment: If you want _performance_, I think an [unboxed vector](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.1/docs/Data-Vector-Unboxed.html) of `Bool` is the way to go. The runtime representation has no pointers at all, and stores one boolean per word.

Comment: It's not totally clear to me what you're asking. You claim to want "map, fold, filter, etc." which don't sound particularly useful for an abstract array of booleans.

Comment: @jberryman Yes, you're right. My mistake. I use these primitives when I work with `Float` values but I forgot that I never use them when working with `Bool` values. I just need to be able to iterate over the collection. I need things like the n-th intersection with the x-axis, average/max/min number of samples between intersections, etc.

Comment: @ThomasVanhelden How about an unboxed Vector Word32/64, with each word representing the length of the span? Even indexes and odd indexes respectively will have the same sign (I believe). n-th intersection is just `!`. And those aggregates could be maintained as you consume samples, but otherwise would just be `Vector.max` etc.

Comment: @jberryman That sounds like it could work! I will give it a try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both one-bool-per-byte and one-bool-per-bit options are available from the `vector` and `array` packages respectively.

First, a `Vector Bool` from `Data.Vector.Unboxed` uses a byte array with one byte per `Bool`.  This can be verified from the source in module `Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base` where `Vector Bool` is defined as:

```
newtype instance Vector    Bool = V_Bool  (P.Vector    Word8)
```

and getting and setting are mediated through the functions:

```
fromBool :: Bool -> Word8
toBool :: Word8 -> Bool
```

Alternatively, it can be verified directly by profiling the program:

```
import Data.Vector.Unboxed as V
main = let v = V.replicate 1000000000 True
  in print (v ! 5)
```

and observing that it allocates just over 1,000,000,000 bytes.

Second, a `UArray Int Bool` from `Data.Array.Unboxed` is implemented as a bit vector, with one `Bool` per bit.  The relevant source is in `Data.Array.Base`, where you can see the bit manipulation used in the instance:

```
instance IArray UArray Bool where
    ...
    unsafeAt (UArray _ _ _ arr#) (I# i#) = isTrue#
        ((indexWordArray# arr# (bOOL_INDEX i#) `and#` bOOL_BIT i#)
        `neWord#` int2Word# 0#)
```

Again, this can be verified directly by profiling:

```
import Data.Array.Unboxed as A
main = let v = A.listArray (1,1000000000) (repeat True) :: UArray Int Bool
  in print (v ! 5)
```

and verifying that it allocates approximately 125,000,000 bytes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I find it really interesting! Correct me if I'm wrong but `Vector` is faster and `Array` is more memory-efficient for my problem?

Comment: Well, `Array` is certainly likely to be be much more memory-efficient than `Vector`, but as to the speed, that might depend a lot on the specific algorithm.  I think benchmarking will be the only way to answer that.